# Best Practice for Procedural Generation and Code Updates

Tags: java, procedural-generation, php

I am using an initial seed to generate data.
The question I have though is what is the best way to mantain the information with code updates.
For example if I have something similar to:

```
initial_seed = 1;
mount_seed( initial_seed );
var weather = ['snow','sun',rain','fog'];
shuffle(weather);
current weather = weather[0]; // sun
// a bunch of code and variables
abc = rand(1,100); // 20
```

The problem is if I do updates to the 'weather' variable, it will break all the code after.

```
initial_seed = 1;
mount_seed( initial_seed );
var weather = ['snow','sun',rain','fog','windy'];
shuffle(weather);
current weather = weather[0]; // fog
// a bunch of code and variables
abc = rand(1,100); // 76
```

My initial thought was to save the variables 'current weather', etc and load those up instead of the seeds. It would make version control easier since the variables are saved and loaded.
The problem is when I have thousands of variables with different lengths, the save files get bloated.
The other option would be to save the initial seed and a version of the code and load up the seed and version every time.
I'm curious what the most scaleable option would be as well as how other bigger companies have come at this issue.

Comment: Are "bloated save files" really that much of a problem? Disk storage is cheap, and it's not even your storage. Minecraft, for example, stores all already generated chunks on disk, and there are no complaints.

Comment: For the specific case of picking from a predetermined list, it would be possible to pick a fixed upper limit on the size of the list, and write a shuffle implementation that always uses the same number of RNG calls, as long as the list is that length or shorter. Whether that is worth the effort is something you need to decide.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is if I do updates to the 'weather' variable, it will break all the code after.

The less you do, the better. If you are only picking a weather at random, you probably don't need to shuffle the array. Just get a random number up to the number of elements. It would always be a single call regardless of how many options are there.

---

> My initial thought was to save the variables 'current weather', etc and load those up instead of the seeds. It would make version control easier since the variables are saved and loaded. The problem is when I have thousands of variables with different lengths, the save files get bloated.

That is probably not a problem. In particular if the variables don't change often. At least not for one or a few worlds generated per server. *I suppose you don't go from rain, to snow, to fog, to windy, by walking a few steps. So these variables don't need be stored with high resolution.*

However, if you want to have a single server for many large worlds, at some point it would become an issue. *You would face some other issues before you get there.*

I'll be assuming that many large worlds in the same server is the situation from here on.

---

> The other option would be to save the initial seed and a version of the code and load up the seed and version every time.

Let me tell you a "secret": code is data. Do not think about storing a version of the code that generates the world. Think about storing a description of how to generate the world. It could be as simple as a file with a list of variable names and what are their possible values, plus the seed and any other metadata needed. Then - in code - for any variable that needs a value, you can see if it is in the file, and generate it according to it.

Thus, no, it would be keeping the old code. Instead it is generating as faithful as possible in the newer version of the code. And thus, you would not be maintaining (i.e. providing technical support for) multiple versions of the code.

"But wait" - I imagine you say - "the order in which they are generated matters. Also, what about variables that are not in the file?".

---

I have a solution for you. *Which - by the way - I think deserves to gain popularity.* We are going to use noise. "Pff." -  I imagine you say - "that is nothing new". And you are right. However, we will not use noise how it first comes to mind. *You can - of course - use some noise function for generation  - e.g. terrain elevation and such. That is not what I'm suggesting, in fact, I'll assume you are already doing something like that.*

I want you to have some other noise you can use for extra variables (it might also be extra dimension on some noise you have). Then to pick your random values by reading a position from that noise. *You can store as metadata on the descriptor file, what are the coordinates in noise space for each variable (it can be the coordinates from the world, plus some coordinates form the file).*

If you need a variable number of random values (e.g. for shuffle requiring a number of random values depending on the number of elements), you define a ray (some initial position and a step vector) in noise space to read from. *And - of course - store that as the metadata for the shuffle in the descriptor file.*

This removes the problem of ordering. *Inserting more calls to get a random value will no longer affect other calls done afterwards.* That way, adding a new option to `weather`, which means more calls to generate random numbers, only affects `weather`. It does not mess with the generation of anything else.

---

And about the extra variables... If you have variables that are not in the descriptor file, it means it is from an old version. But that is no problem: you can add any missing variables to the descriptor file, knowing they will not affect the others thanks to using noise as I explained above.

Removed variables? That just means some parts of the descriptor file are ignored. You could remove them.

---

OK, let us say you want to keep the world up to where the players explored generated with the old version, but continue with the new version. What then? Then you would have two descriptor files, or more. You would need to know for what parts of the world use what file. *Which is much less data than storing the value of every variable for each part of the world.*

In this case, you probably don't want extra variables to be randomized in old files. For that you can give them a constant default value.

By the way, storing what file to use where compresses very well, because a lot of contiguous areas would be using the same file. In fact, you might want to store this with even less resolution than the variables it generates. *Since it compresses well, you may want to gzip the files. Or you could even use an image format - which each color referring to a file - and stored them a lossless compression format.*

Knowing what parts are generated with a version and which with another may also allow you to interpolate in the edge to hide any transition artifacts.

---

*You would still need to store any persistent changes to the world that player make. There is no way around that.*

*See also: [Noise-Based RNG - GDC 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWFzPP8ZbdU).*

Comment: Hey there, 
Thanks for the detailed reply.  It has given me a lot to think about. The idea of using noise for random generation is really interesting and something I've never even considered before, but it really does make a lot of sense. Repeatable and also random.  It DOES seem more complicated initially to set up, but the storage costs (at first glance anyway) seem like they would be significant enough to at least give a bit of testing.  Looks like you've just made a lot more work for me. ;)